# else statement gets printed every time along with if statement

Tags: java

Here through constructor I'm initialising my private data member based on a if-else logic. Here is my code below -

```
public BookMyMovie(int movieId, int noOfTickets) {
    
    int arr[]= {101,102,103};
    for(int i: arr)
    {
        if(movieId==i)
        {
            this.movieId=movieId;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry! Invalid Movie ID!\n"
                    + "Please check the Movie ID and enter once again.\n");
        }
    }

    
    this.noOfTickets = noOfTickets;
}
```

So, here I'm only taking id's which falls under one of those three id's declared in the array. But everytime it prints the else statement along with the if. Any advice on this?

Comment: Your loop runs three times for every invocation, and "it runs the else statement along with the if" does not convey useful information. How are you running this? What happens? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: what are the inputs values you tried passing to `BookMyMovie` method

Comment: A few things from viewing your code. Why are you setting your `this.movieId` every time in your conditional `if` statement? In `this.movieId=movieId;` you should have done a `break;` afterwards to stop the loop. This is assuming you want to set `this.movieId` only once. Or, depending on what you want, you just don't set `this.movieId` at all and leave the conditional with no code inside.

Answer (score 0):

You could return after having found the desired movie and only print the error if none is found.

```
public BookMyMovie(int movieId, int noOfTickets) {
    
    this.noOfTickets = noOfTickets;

    int arr[]= {101,102,103};
    for(int i: arr)
    {
        if(movieId==i)
        {
            this.movieId=movieId;
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorry! Invalid Movie ID!\n"
        + "Please check the Movie ID and enter once again.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through the execution of the code. Let's say we call `this.BookMyMovie(101, 2)`.

We will iterate through each element of the array.

On the first iteration, we will have `i = 101`. In this case, we see that `movieId == i` is `true`, so we set `this.movieID` to `101`.

On the second iteration, we will have `i = 102`. In this case, `movieID` does not equal `i`, so we enter the else case.

On the third iteration, we will have `i = 103`, and we again enter the `else` case.

Finally, we set `this.noOfTickets` to `2`.

If this is not what you want to happen, you need to write different code. For example, you could do something like this:

```java
public BookMyMovie(final int movieId, final int noOfTickets) {
    final int[] array = {101, 102, 103};
    final int index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(movieId);
    if (index == -1) {
        System.out.println("Sorry! Invalid Movie ID!\n"
                           + "Please check the Movie ID and enter once again.\n");
    } else {
        this.movieId = array[index];
    }
    this.noOfTickets = noOfTickets;
}
```

Note that you'll need to `import java.util.Arrays` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid repeated looping of array elements by using arraylist and checking if movieId exists in list as below

if required, Storing values in list can be moved out of this method

```
        List<Integer> movieNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        movieNumbers.add(101);
        movieNumbers.add(102);
        movieNumbers.add(103);

        if(movieNumbers.contains(movieId)) {
            System.out.println("It is valid Movie ID!\n");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry! Invalid Movie ID!\n"
                    + "Please check the Movie ID and enter once again.\n");
        }
```